# Passing dom node to a directive without template referance variable

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to pass a dom node to a function in a directive to add a class to that node. Here is the working plunker. This is working fine but i want to pass the dom node without a reference variable or is there a better way of doing it ?
https://plnkr.co/edit/9gBG0MXxeqlGB3eTau1T?p=preview

```
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {
   }
    @ViewChild(changeStyleClass) vc: changeStyleClass;
    @ViewChild('h1Ref') h1: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('mbc') mbc: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vc.addClass(this.h1.nativeElement, 'redColor');
    this.vc.addClass(this.mbc.nativeElement, 'makeBorder');
  }
  }
}
```

Please look at the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9gBG0MXxeqlGB3eTau1T?p=preview) for the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use view bindings like `[class.foo]="..."` or `[ngClass]="..."` if you want to add a class to an element in the view

```
<h1 [class.redColor]="isRedColor">
```

```
  isRedColor:boolean = false;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isRedColor = true;
    ...
  }
```

**update**

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  afterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('h1').classList.add('redColor');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is true but in my case; I want to hide the bootstrap modal so i have to remove and add a class.i want to pass the node to the directive without the template reference variable  https://plnkr.co/edit/9gBG0MXxeqlGB3eTau1T?p=preview

Comment: Do i not need renderer here?

Comment: You can, but you don't need to. It is required if you want to use server-side rendering or Angulars WebWorker feature.

Comment: There are dozens of answers that demonstrate how to do it already. I'm sure you will be able to find one.

Comment: ok. Please tell me why my way is not better than your way of doin it.

Comment: I didn't say my way is better. The difference is, that you don't need a template variable - whuch I think is what you asked for?

Comment: Ok. So I can have a directive to add a class. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can use `ngClass` which is a directive, or your own.